# How to make an initialism out of a word/phrase with a number?

Tags: abbreviations, initialisms

I have a question. How do I make an initialism out of a word/phrase with a number?

**For an example:** Should `Rainbow 6 Siege` be `R6S` because of initialism is an abbreviation made of initial letters but `6` is not a letter.

Comment: This gets me wondering about R2-D2 and C-3PO.

Comment: @Jeeped I think they are just series number of the droid and not an abbreviation of anything. Like `R2-D2` stands for R2 series astromech droid.

Comment: If initialism means what I think it does, then you can't. The best you can do is an abbreviation like W3C (World Wide Web Consortium), K9, G20, MI5. Your R6S would be an abbreviation, I don't think it would meet the requirements for either acronym or initialism. Abbreviation though, yes. Interestingly most of these abbreviations are listed under the Wikipedia acronym article, though I don't think it contends they are acronyms. Is it an unimportant point whether your abbreviation is an initialism or acronym or any other 'thing'?

Comment: What about *RSS*, where the first *S* stands for *six*, the word that represents the numeral?

Comment: @Zebrafish Thanks! So all I do is just to abbreviate to make it understandable because it can't be an initialism.

Comment: @JasonBassford I remembered `RSS` is the one accepted by the community but most people use `R6S` (maybe got mistaken for RSS feed?)

Comment: Should this question be answered, please write your answer as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to use a '**numeronym**'

A `numeronym` is a word where a number is used to form an abbreviation, such as K9 for canine, or W3 for World Wide Web etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym

Your reference of `Rainbow 6 Siege` as `R6S` is a perfectly acceptable numeronym.